# Persona for Web Designer Portfolio Website

Tags: web-development, website-design

I'm working on my first real portfolio website and I learned in one of my Web Design classes at ASU that we web designers should write up a Persona for our "target market" (who we think will be the typical visitor). I'm guessing that mostly recruiters and HR people will be the most likely people to view my portfolio website.

What are the most typical aspects of recruiters and HR people who would be looking for an entry level web designer/developer like me? Here are the categories we learned in class:

- Name:
- Age: (or age range)
- Gender:
- Education: (Bachelor's, Master's, PhD?)
- Work Experience: (Been a recruiter for 10 years straight?)
- Likes and Dislikes: (Goes to the bar after work every Friday; Love to tag themselves and friends on FourSquare at those bars; Loves long walks on the beach...?)
- Personality: (Type "A"; Easy-going; fed up with social injustice...?)
- Communication style: (Prefers texting; loves to talk on the phone all night; gets a "boost" from chatting with friends in person...?)
- Computer skills: (Barely knows where the power switch is; has a Master's in IT; knows just enough to get by in an office environment...?)
- Frequency of Internet Usage: (Every day but only at work; on Facebook and Twitter nearly every waking hour; "Internet...? What's that?"...?)
- Websites Visited on Frequent Basis: (google only; facebook, pinterest; yahoo only...?)
- Knowledge of Subject of Your Website: (Fresh out of college, having just obtained Communications degree; master web designer; was a social media expert for a while...?)
- Key Reasons Why to Visit Your Website: (This one might seem obvious based on my assumptions of who's going to visit - "find a match for the position(s) I'm trying to fill" - but if you can think of anything else, by all means, please say something)
- Key Needs from a Website on Your Subject: (Quick and easy way to contact me; a link/button to easily download a copy of my resume to share with the hiring manager (what document format? .docx, .pdf?)...?)

According to the class, the answers to all of the above categories will help the web designer decide how to design (colors, fonts, layout, menus, etc.) and format (one page, multiple pages, etc.) the site in question.

Comment: In case you're wondering, I already finished the class. Here, I'm asking about my own personal web design portfolio website now. I want to use what I learned to professionally and correctly design and develop my own portfolio website. Please notice that I gave several examples after each of the categories - so, it should be easy to see that I've already done my own "homework" so to speak on this. But, I'm not a recruiter or HR person, so I might not have a clear understanding of what the typical recruiter or HR person will be looking for/need when they visit my portfolio.

Comment: Sorry but the question is to board (too many possible answers), too specific (unlikely to help anyone else), opinionated (what companies look for vary from company to company) and as well as being off-topic (not a webmaster related question)  To avoid future disappointment I recommend you visit our help center.

Comment: You are better off talking to recruiters and HR people. You can also check out ere.net and troll around there for a while. You will not be able to participate, but you will gain unreal insight into this business and the personalities involved. You will definitely gain marketing insight there! I used to be involved in this world. It is the primiere HR - Recruiter website and is like SE in a lot of respects- very professional!

Comment: One hint. They are more likely to vote for Obama a third time. As well, all have degrees- you have to work in the field, but they are not necessary computer literate and have trouble with using technology and are way behind the times. As well, you will find some similarity with the SEO world- topic de' jure, a lot of speculation, a lot of so-called experts parroting what some expert says. They do not want to work past 5pm, would rather not talk on the phone or to anyone for that matter, will make you do most of the work, do not give a rip about your goals only the bottom line, impatient, etc.

Comment: I think the best way is to hand out numerous of resumes to companies that are hiring regardless of how fit you are for the position then in the interview rooms you enter, write down every question that you are asked.

Comment: closetnoc & Mike -- Thank you very much! Your answers were extremely helpful. I can't thank you enough! I'm off to troll around ere.net.